# Basic Grammar - の particle as an explanation

Tags: particles

I'm an absolute Japanese learning beginner. I came across this confusing sentence while I was reading a grammar guide book. Please help me :
**飲むんだ。**
I understand that の is substituted by ん as we speak, but I'm not sure what's the exact meaning of the whole sentence. "I drunk" or is it only an adjective and if so, what does it mean ?

Comment: `I drunk` -> Sorry but I don't really understand, did you mean to type "I drank" or "I drink" ?

Answer (score 2):

> 「[飲]{の}むんだ。」

Unless the context proved otherwise, that would be a request/order.  It would be masculine speech nearly 100% of the time.

> "Drink it up!"

The "other" main usage of 「～～のだ/んだ」 is when you explain (rather assertively) the reason or cause for something.

> 「飲まないと[眠]{ねむ}れないから**飲むんだ**！」

=

> "I drink (alcohol) because I couldn't sleep if I didn't drink!"

Comment: Thanks, so if we translate word by word, that would be : The thing （ん） is （だ）that let's drink （飲む）, right ?

Comment: Word-for-word translation is difficult here.  I recommend that you memorize the two usages as if 「のだ/んだ」 were a set phrase or sentence-ender.

Answer (score 0):

I just replied today to a question that I believe might concern the same topic you are being confused by (since you don't give much context is a bit hard to say for sure).

Anyway, if I'm correct it might be an interesting reading:

[aru vs arun -- are they exactly the same grammar-wise?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/aru-vs-arun-are-they-exactly-the-same-grammar-wise)